# Coinpayment Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, coinpayments-api

I have installed Coinpayment with https://github.com/hexters/CoinPayment inside mine project.

The problem what i;m getting is Coinpayments can't send IPN request to mine server or there is somewhere timeout.
Now i have try all option and try to reinstall i'm not getting success to solve this problem.

Here is the picture what i'm getting in Coinpayments

[image]

ENV file

```
COINPAYMENT_PUBLIC_KEY=x
COINPAYMENT_PRIVATE_KEY=x
COINPAYMENT_CURRENCY=EUR
COINPAYMENT_IPN_ACTIVATE=true
COINPAYMENT_MARCHANT_ID=x
COINPAYMENT_IPN_SECRET=x
COINPAYMENT_IPN_DEBUG_EMAIL=x
```

I have also add the path for Except in App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken

```
protected $except = [
        '/coinpayment/ipn',
    ];
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem it seems mine friend has turn the Laravel project offline when i was busy thats why coinpayments IPN can't connect with the laravel project.
thanks @larabee for your support

Answer (score 0):

at first you need to know that coinpayment/ipn adress should accessable from outside, 
on which hoster you have uploaded the project?

Sometimes there are firewalls around the server which makes it unuasble
Can you check that? More informations you can find in the  check the Webserver access-Logfiles.

Sometimes there are Status 502 (Bad Gateway) or HTTP-Status 503 errors.

Comment: Hello, I have vps server at vultr and yes i just checked the logs it give: 149.56.241.110 - - [17/Feb/2020:21:31:04 +0000] "POST /coinpayment/ipn HTTP/1.1" 503 5259 "-" "CoinPayments.net IPN Generator" I have disabled the firewall but it still give me same log: sudo ufw status
Status: inactive